# How to create Lua tables automatically

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I'm working on a really simple interpreter for a really simple programming language, and I'm currently trying to pull out a section of code to interpret should a condition be met. Currently that code to evaluate is between the keywords `compare` and `endcompare` and what I'd like to happen is the following:

- Remove everything after and up to `endcompare` from the original list of tokens, keeping `compare` in that list.
- Put the removed tokens into another table which is to be evaluated when `compare` is found in the original table, this does not include the `endcompare`.

Basically:

```
original = {"a", "b", "c", "compare", "this", "please", "whatever", "endcompare", "d"}
```

After this "magic" function, produce the following:

```
new = {"a", "b", "c", "compare", "d"}
c = {"this", "please", "whatever"}
```

In this case, `new` will be evaluated, and when the keyword `compare` is encountered, evaluate `c` and return back to `new`.

I've had a few attempts so far and none have been successful, unless you count reversing part of the table or skipping every other token...

How would I go about creating said table?

Comment: OK, so... what's your question?

Comment: @NicolBolas I realized I wasn't very precise in phrasing my question (and by that I mean I didn't)

Comment: You already have a parser for this "language" of yours? It creates tables like `original` for you currently? You have code that can "evaluate" the `new` table and understand what to to when it sees the `compare` entry? (How dose it know what table to evaluate for `compare`?

Comment: @EtanReisner It just reads a file and separates the keywords by whitespace, then does stuff depending on what the keyword is, like when it sees `compare` it would execute the compare block that I'm trying to pull out. Like I said I am aware of the limitations of this implementation and I will likely change it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you're looking for, but I haven't tested it:

```
function produceTwo(original)
 local newT, c, go = {}, {}, false
 for i,v in ipairs(original) do
  if v == "compare" then
   go = true
   continue
  elseif v == "endcompare" then
   go = false
   continue
  end

  if go then
   table.insert(c, v) 
  else
   table.insert(newT, v)
  end
 end
 return newT, c
end
```

Comment: `continue` is not a keyword in Lua, but you can use `goto continue` and put `::continue::` at the end of the loop. Also this does work, but does not keep the `continue` in the original. It wouldn't be too hard to re-insert it in though. Thanks